# Why we use count variable & and how its work?

Tags: python, variables, count

#program of prime number from 2 to 100

```
for i in range (2,100):
   count = 0
   for j in range(1, i+1):
       if i % j = 0:
           count = count + 1
       if count == 2:
           print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code seems to not work due to a syntax error(might be a typo).
**if conditions** in python, requires double equals (==).

> if i % j **==** 0:

In the question you posted, the count variable acts as a flag or counter variable.
A prime number is a number which can only be perfectly divided, by 1 or the number itself. (eg: 11 can be divided by 1 and 11 only, therefore a prime number)

So  the counter variable i.e. **count** holds the number of times that a number(2-200) gets perfectly divided(i.e. (%) modulo operation results in value 0). If the value of count is 2 then we can confirm that it is a prime number since a prime number can only be divided with 1 and the number itself (hence count=2). And if the count == 2 after all the possible divisions happening in the j loop (2nd for loop), we can conclude that it is a prime number.

```
for i in range (2,200):
    count = 0
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        if i % j == 0:
            count += 1
    if count == 2:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` variable is being used to ensure if the particular number `i` is being divisible by any other number other than 1. Because if it does, then it is not a prime number. The moment it becomes 2, it means that number is divisible by 1 and some other number less than `i` proving it be a non-prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to get primes from 100, you can change the 100 to whatever you want

```
for num in range(100):
    if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               print(num,"is not a prime number")
               print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
               break
       else:
           print(num,"is a prime number")
    else:
       print(num,"is not a prime number")
```